# Is it possible to show the database values in jquery thickbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In hiddenModalContent div is it possible to display the database value as once thickbox is opening it just showing nothing

```
<?php
foreach($this->list_details as $key=>$details)
{?>
<a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=false" class="thickbox"><div class="sc_content_subheading"><? echo $this->escape($details['list_name'])?></div></a>
<div id="hiddenModalContent" style="display:none;">
<span class="content_subheading">List name&nbsp;</span><? echo $details['list_name'];?><br/>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you are only outputting the list name. What else in the array would you like to show?

Comment: just for example iam showing the list name there are some more details to show there

Comment: So why can't you just echo the extra details? You said the list name is showing.

Comment: sorry List name i mean just label in span List name not the value it is showing